# cytoscape source-label target-label

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I am trying to use the source-label and target-label style in a JavaScript code.
In my code I am currently using this (it is working fine)

```
cy.$("#"+myClickedID).style('label', myClickedID)
```

I would like to use something like this (but is doesn't work)

```
cy.$("#"+myClickedID).style('source-label', 'start')
cy.$("#"+myClickedID).style('target-label', 'end')
```

Am I missing something (probably yes) ?

Answer (score 0):

Source and target labels are specified on edges, not nodes.  See http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/labels

Comment: I doing it on an edge, see below he code

cy.on('click', 'edge', function(evt){
var myClickedID = evt.cyTarget.id();
if (cy.$('#' + myClickedID).style('label').length < 1){
cy.$("#"+myClickedID).style('source-label', myClickedID)
 } else {
cy.$("#"+myClickedID).style('source-label', '')
}
});